# flex match multiline grouping

Tags: regex, bison, flex-lexer

Trying to make flex parse this stuff as if the contents of {} is one block (could match each line which I could buffer)

```
[file] file_content1 = {}
[file] file_content2 = { blah }
[file] file_content3 = { multi
line
content3}
[file] file_content4 = {
multi
line
content4
}
```

The rule I have setup is basically as

```
<PATH_STATE>"\{" {
    BEGIN(CONTENT_STATE);
}

<CONTENT_STATE>{
    "\}" {
        BEGIN(PATH_STATE);
        return TOK_CONTENT;
    }
    <<EOF>> {
        // eof error
    }
    (.)*/\} {
        lval.s = strdup(yytext);
    }
}
```

The above works for the first 2 lines, I can successfully get the contents, but it fails for the multiline part. Is it possible or should I trap the \n in this state and buffer each line?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In (f)lex, `.` does not match a newline. On the other hand, `[^}]` does match a newline and does not match a `}`, which I guess is what you are looking for. With that, there is no need to use a start condition:

```
[{][^}]*[}] {
              yylval.s = strdup(yytext + 1);
              yylval.s[yyleng - 2] = 0;
            }
[{]         { /* Eof inside  braces error */ }
```

If you don't like the overallocation by one byte if yylval.s, you could use

```
yylval.s = malloc(yyleng - 1);
memcpy(yylval.s, yytext + 1, yyleng - 2);
yylval.s[yyleng - 2] = 0;
```

It may be that you want to allow nested braces in blocks. In that case, the start condition would be necessary, and the use of `yymore` would be useful.